# Webflow get Event Id in Controller

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Is there a way to get the _eventId parameter from the SWF RequestContext? Sometimes I need to use a bit of logic to decide where to transition to:

```
public String processATransition(RequestContext requestContext) {
    String eventId = ?

    if (eventId.equals("PREV")) {
        if (currentViewState.equals("search")) {
          return "searchParameters";
        } else {
          return "start";
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by:

```
    String eventId = requestContext.getCurrentEvent().getId();
```